# Как занести одиночные динамичные данные в БД

Tags: php, laravel

Доброго времени суток!

Например есть сайт на Laravel PHP, заказчик сказал чтобы была возможность редактировать последовательность вывода баннеров, или же возможность редактировать заголовок и описание заголовка на главной странице, числа, проценты и т.д.. Как это лучше реализовать? Создавать новую таблицу в SQL? Я использую Laravel с админ панелью MoonShine.